# What is Mage_Catalog_Block_Product ? Is it the path of price.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, blocks, static-block, phtml

I need to call `$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);` to my newly created block.

I called the product image, name and etc... but I didn't able to call the price.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
$manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_product')->getManufacturer();

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', $manufacturer);

/** I have tried with this**/
$productCollection = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract;

$productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$productCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);

if ($productCollection->getSize() > 0) {
    foreach ($productCollection as $_product):
        ?>
        <div class="random-brand-products">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
               title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img
                    src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(228) ?>"
                    width="228" height="228" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"/></a>

            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name"><a
                        href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a>
                </p>

                <?php
                $merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');
                if ($merchant_name) {
                    ?>
                    <div>by <?php echo $merchant_name; ?> </div>
                <?php } else if ($_product->getIsEbayaffiliate()) { ?>
                    <div>by eBay</div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <div>by Home Done</div>
                <?php } ?> </div>

            /** I have tried with this**/
            $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);

        </div>
        <?php
    endforeach;
} else {
    echo "There are no products matching the selection";
}
?>
```

I think I am doing something wrong the class `$productCollection = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract;`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_product')->getManufacturer();

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$manufacturer);
$productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$productCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);

if($productCollection->getSize()>0){
    /** Try this **/
    $block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('catalog/product_price'); // or $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price') if exists
    foreach ($productCollection as $_product):
        ?>
        <div class="random-brand-products">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(228) ?>" width="228" height="228" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
            <div class="product-details">
                <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></p>

                <?php
                $merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');
                if ($merchant_name){?>
                    <div>by <?php echo $merchant_name;?> </div>
                <?php }

                else if ($_product->getIsEbayaffiliate()) { ?>
                    <div>by eBay</div>
                <?php }

                else { ?>
                    <div>by Home Done</div>
                <?php } ?> </div>
            <?php
            $price = $block->getPriceHtml($_product);
            echo $price;
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    endforeach;
}else{
    echo "There are no products matching the selection";
}
?>
```

Comment: getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in  line 13"

Comment: @Doodu Please, show the complete file here (with line 13)

Comment: I used the code you suggested above... No changes in that code...

Comment: @Doodu It's strange, becouse the "IF" condition not exist on line 13.  Could you update the your question with the actual code (copy-paste)?

Comment: It works... I didn't realize there was 2 options you given in line 13 "$block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('catalog/product_price'); // or 
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price') if exists" ;)